# How to relatively move number of objects by moving one of them with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a question.

I have 4 Image View objects is my storyboard. Those represents "corners". I'd like to have this option, when you move one of corners, and other three moves relatively.

Like on [animated gif here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xmh3g.gif)

What I do now is applying Pan Gesture Recognizer to Image Views in storyboard. Then I add code to ViewController:

```
 @IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
    recognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x:recognizer.view!.center.x + translation.x,
        y:recognizer.view!.center.y + translation.y)
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)

}
```

But I'm not sure what to do next. I need to recognise which corner is tapped and moving, so I could apply special relation moving function for other corners.

Comment: Well, monitor the dragging of each element and apply the transformed move to the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heyo,

One technique is to find a vector representing the pan gesture, and then using that vector to update the rest of the  image views. For instance, UIPanGestureRecognizers extends from UIGestureRecognizer, which has the method:

`func locationOfTouch(_ touchIndex: Int, inView view: UIView?) -> CGPoint`

The pseudocode would go somewhat like this:

1. Get 1 imageView's last known location as a CGPoint
2. Detect the pan gesture
3. Retrieve the location of the touch, as a CGPoint

Now that you have two CGPoints, 1 representing the start position and 1 representing the end position, you can subtract the two points to form a vector with a length and direction. Using this information, you can come up with a formula to displace the other 3 imageViews.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. It seems reasonable. But as far as I'm a noob in coding yet, I would like to ask you to be a bit more specific on this technique please.

Comment: @KonstantinBashenko This is not the place to learn, just to get your broken code fixed. Please use other resources for learning.

Comment: @ThomasKilian I would argue on this. It is kind of a place to learn. But to learn thing in special way. Stackoverflow is kind of a knowledge base. Wouldn't it be great to have more detailed answer for such question, so future researchers could have an answer? Any way, I will figure it out from this point. But I would post my solution before closing this question.

Comment: No. This is not a tutorial place. You need to get other resources to delve into certain topics. Sure, a detailed explanation is better than a short one. But above is (from my POV) in the right size for SO.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Yes, Mr. Kilian, I guess you right. It's just I'm stuck on such simple thing. And I have no idea even what to return from Kelvin's function.

Comment: Then you should go back one step and try something a bit easier. Drag a simple object first with a gesture. Then watch its movement and apply that (with reverse delta x/y as appropriate) to the other three objects.